# Error while trying to import json file

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json file I need to import into my Angular 2 application. I've followed steps from this [How to Import json into TypeScript](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79) article but I'm getting a "`SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`" error. What do you think am I doing wrong?

Here's my code:

**Full error:**

```
(index):28 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
        at eval (<anonymous>)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:37967/Application/Settings.js:3:19)
        at eval (http://localhost:37967/Application/Settings.js:92:4)
        at eval (http://localhost:37967/Application/Settings.js:93:3)
        at eval (<anonymous>)
    Evaluating http://localhost:37967/appSettings.json
    Evaluating http://localhost:37967/Application/Settings.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:37967/Application/BaseComponent.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:37967/Application/Components/Home/Home.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:37967/Application/Module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:37967/Application/Startup.js
    Error loading http://localhost:37967/Application/Startup.js
```

**Settings.ts:**

```
/// <reference path="../scripts/typescriptdefinitions/typings.d.ts" />
..
import * as appSettings from '../../appSettings.json';
..
    public static get AppSettings(): any{
        return <any>appSettings;
    }
..
```

**typings.d.ts:**

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

**appSettings.json:**

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "Url": ...
  }
}
```

I've checked the Network panel and the file is loaded with `200 OK`. Also the json contents are valid json.

Comment: Question question: FMY could me please explain me the purpose of importing json file vs loading it with http.request()?

Comment: @Vega: loading it with http is async. The json file contains url for an API and I've API calls on the main page and I've had errors because the calls on the main page executing before the json http request completed. import is sync so this eliminates that problem.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you refer to was designed to run in a CommonJS environment, presumably Node. In such case the `import` statement becomes a `require` statement. In node doing `require("foo.json")` is perfectly fine: Node knows that it should not try to *execute* the JSON file.

However, if you are not loading a CommonJS module in Node, **you *usually* need to tell the bundler or loader that a JSON file must be treated specially**. Otherwise, the tool will think that you are loading code, and will try to execute it.

The error messages you have suggest to me that you are using SystemJS. With SystemJS you want to set your SystemJS configuration with a `meta` that will tell SystemJS that the file you are trying to load should be loaded with the `json` loader:

```
  meta: {
    "path/to/file": {
      loader: "json",
    },
  },
```

And you need to have `systemjs-plugin-json` installed. `path/to/file` could contain a wildcard if you have multiple files you need loading as `json`. For instance, I have `project/config/*` so that all files in `project/config/` are treated as JSON. Unfortunately, what wildcards SystemJS supports is not very well documented, so you may have to try and see what works for you.